# AAD OAuth returning invalid_grant error when requesting token

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I was able to successfully retrieve an authorization code from the `/authorize` endpoint, but when I request the Access Token using that auth code, I get an "invalid_grant" response: [Postman request and response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQjaD.png)

Has anyone experienced this and/or know the fix? I've tried almost every form of body parameters in Postman: `none`, `form-data`, `x-www-form-urlencoded`, `raw/JSON`... I've also tried multiple auth codes and different scopes to try to get a different result with no success.

I've followed every tutorial online about this and set up my Azure AD correctly but I cannot figure out why I am receiving this error.

Comment: Please add the authorization request. It's hard to tell from a screenshot but you're `authorization_code` looks suspiciously like an access token rather than an auth code.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you shared, it looks like you have entered a wrong value in your code parameter.
[image]

The value you entered in the code parameter doesn't look like a code issued by AAD moreover it looks like a JWT. A code should look something like:

```
0.AAAADwfHAumwK0KsP2ZEpOVNJu04rXpoeNlIrnwTJMFkhlh3AMI.AQABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrqKRiGvR5OuLcyEswwCbukgoiXScUQpKdYgWxZ1aezF87g_qZgNL2lRX_10n06RANe4sREo9k62OP0qYEy2WEiDKhqLFO-ye0Vr5l0KkfyjEcFMfpH7EU6KMZmWhILdZtJmHT0-TmPjN1agJTUDbR3sdP-qWotGCq4R6ZRp5AIsJhqwUuv9rnUxI975j5zBuJe2Y1kg96oFFcMKrl4mDbanTGDMwLne5RmHyl3nO3qUnosUJ3eKKUxf0aaUqhZxPoPjhVzaTah_wwLG9aGlV7LwyrzxkG17uNsL9PWREMPVLdR9OcOHohM9truHu_eNLS5Cf3WxKcjwBttPKETEs565bJB765E3P04P3j85yW6AigS38-Wi6IWyj-PFEd5FSLebgenQMNHeTunufjS8k3FebLsBi3jI5w4D0NCbS3YGvS8trbb-DyFst8Jqq5ALZhawsXTZhpsR3rosKt15lk7W0PJArg-xvs36GWwg6MAgZ4vCM4AIqC9HAjz09SpoBgEiE7h58uMTG3H7E7OFGqvjuxVxztVQO0vclbdJxhplmx2DEk29eQherVstaeYLx7sLmHArN3D_r2ublDAyQSQcdQtwOroHQQEwSf7FHmnbGRmXI4ZOMX726qkinSJBc-oNnH4UNPb_LgV2FG8mF8vyAA
```

In case of Authorization Code Grant flow, first step is to hit the **/authorize** endpoint of AAD and request for a code. In the next step, you make a call to the **/token** endpoint and submit that code and after redeeming of the code, AAD issues you an access-token and other tokens (id-token and refresh-token) based on the value of the scope parameters.

TO test, you can use the following request to the **/authorize** endpoint and fetch the code from there:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client-id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&response_mode=fragment&scope=openid%20offline_access&state=12345
```

Since I have used the **response_mode** as **fragment** here, after the user enters the credentials and AAD sends the code, you should get a response on your browser something like: `redirect_uri#code=xxx-xxx-xxx&state=12345&session_state=7030291f-8215-4c6c-bee7-5b7901c28ef6`

For eg:

```
https://localhost:1234/#code=0.AAAADwfHAumwK0KsP2ZEpOVNJu04rXpoeNlIrnwTJMFkhlh3AMI.AQABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrqKRiGvR5OuLcyEswwCbukgoiXScUQpKdYgWxZ1aezF87g_qZgNL2lRX_10n06RANe4sREo9k62OP0qYEy2WEiDKhqLFO-ye0Vr5l0KkfyjEcFMfpH7EU6KMZmWhILdZtJmHT0-TmPjN1agJTUDbR3sdP-qWotGCq4R6ZRp5AIsJhqwUuv9rnUxI975j5zBuJe2Y1kg96oFFcMKrl4mDbanTGDMwLne5RmHyl3nO3qUnosUJ3eKKUxf0aaUqhZxPoPjhVzaTah_wwLG9aGlV7LwyrzxkG17uNsL9PWREMPVLdR9OcOHohM9truHu_eNLS5Cf3WxKcjwBttPKETEs565bJB765E3P04P3j85yW6AigS38-Wi6IWyj-PFEd5FSLebgenQMNHeTunufjS8k3FebLsBi3jI5w4D0NCbS3YGvS8trbb-DyFst8Jqq5ALZhawsXTZhpsR3rosKt15lk7W0PJArg-xvs36GWwg6MAgZ4vCM4AIqC9HAjz09SpoBgEiE7h58uMTG3H7E7OFGqvjuxVxztVQO0vclbdJxhplmx2DEk29eQherVstaeYLx7sLmHArN3D_r2ublDAyQSQcdQtwOroHQQEwSf7FHmnbGRmXI4ZOMX726qkinSJBc-oNnH4UNPb_LgV2FG8mF8vyAA&state=12345&session_state=7030291f-8215-4c6c-bee7-5b7901c28ef6
```

Extract the code from the above response and then enter that code as a value to the code parameter in the body of the request being sent to the **/token** endpoint and it should work.